# "select 2*2 as 'm', (m*2) as 'n';" returns error

Tags: mysql, alias

Executing `select 2*2 as 'm', (m*2) as 'n'` returns

```
 /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'm' in 'field list' */
```

Is there any way for using a alias of a column  in the columns clause ?

also:

```
select sum(x) as sum, sum*2 as doubleSum from myTable;
```

Comment: already answered, stop editing >.<

Comment: @AdrianBR How funny comment!

Comment: you kept changing the question. If you have a different question after the existing got answered, post a different question. I got neg voted on answer because your question changed.

Comment: check my answer btw for your last edit from 15min ago >.< Variables work if you use the correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with variables, like

```
select @m:=2*2 as m, @m*2 as n
```

-you may want to use `n` later (actually, that will be `@n` that you will be able to use, but not `n` directly), then it will be

```
select @m:=2*2 as m, @n:=@m*2 as n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a sub-query:

```
select m, (m*2) as n
from
(
  select 2*2 as m
) sub_query
```

Comment: subquery adds time, unnecessary

Comment: @AdrianBR yet in the same time it will work in other DBMS since it is a valid SQL which does not rely on DBMS-specific features, like MySQL variables

Comment: the question is for MySQL. Why would you use a slower variant if you have an excellent native function and portability is not required

Comment: I'm not saying this is better (but trust - me, subquery overhead means nothing in this case). It's just another way to get result - which fits OP's question (and my point was only to show benefits of this solution)

Comment: For mysql I would still choose a one liner vs a 5 liner. Also, in production every milisecond counts. In nightly routines, time does not matter, but readability does.

Answer (score 1):

edit: OP edited question

if you want parameters, use following syntax

```
select @m:=2 as m, @m+1 as n

select @m:=2*2 as 'm', (@m*2) as 'n'
```

Also works in real life examples

```
select @sum:=sum(impression) as sum, (@sum)*2 as doubleSum from kpi_funnel;
```

Comment: yeah you can check history